# Simple linear algebra practice problems

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, vectors

So, long story short, I'm trying to teach myself some of the basics of linear algebra (if you want to know why, see the last paragraph). I found an awesome video series on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/eola-topic) that I'm going through to get started. However, there aren't any practice problems on the Khan Academy page.

Where could I find free, simple online problems to practice the stuff I'm learning in the videos? Requirements would be that it is somewhat simpler (I'm in 8th grade), online, and free. I wouldn't mind a textbook if it is, again, online and free. Specifically, right now I just finished  a video about vector multiplication and addition.

As for why I'm trying to teach myself the basics of linear algebra in 8th grade, I'm trying to teach myself a bit about quantum computing, and I found a video series that will teach it (including the quantum mechanics behind it) but it requires some knowledge of linear algebra. So.

Thanks!

Comment: google "linear algebra problems and solutions" : https://www.google.com/#q=linear+algebra+problems+and+solutions - find a link with problems that suit your level.

Comment: [Paul's Notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs485/2006sp/linalg_complete.pdf) are a good textbook resource with some worked examples, but not much in the way of practice problems

Comment: You might like to take a look at http://www.expii.com - they have lessons geared towards high schoolers, and I think they usually have a lot of problems to test yourself with.

Comment: Schaum's Outline isn't free, but it's probably not very expensive, and has large numbers of exercises, with solutions.